# iCloud Aware NSDocument without New Document Button in Open Panel

Tags: swift, icloud, nsdocument

I am writing an NSDocument based app.  It is similar to a spelling or grammar checker in that it can edit documents, but it does not create new ones.

I have removed New from the File menu and the app is iCloud enabled.  When I select Open from the File menu or when the app launches, the open panel has a New Document button.  Since my app does not create new documents, I want to remove that button.  How do I do that?

NSOpenSavePanelDelegate seems like the logical place to do this, but I don't see any provision to remove the New Document button.

I want the app to be iCloud enabled and with no New Document button in the Open Panel.